# Count unique values in JSON file

Tags: python

I have a JSON file with the following setup:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id":123456,
        "name":"John Doe",
        "address":"Address 1"
    }, 
    "2": {
        "id":789011,
        "name":"Name Nameson",
        "address":"Address 2"
    }
}
```

The thing with this file, is that it contains A LOT of duplicates. So what I want is to be able to count how many unique people there are just by their ID. Or really any value they have would work, as no one has the same name or address. So say there are 300 people in the list, and only 50 of them are unique, the rest are duplicates, I want to be able to display that.

I've looked it up on google, but I can't really find anything that works for me...

Comment: How do you define uniqueness? Are there entries with the exact same name and address?

Comment: Hint: once parsed with `json.load()`, this translates to a Python dict of dicts. Then it's just a matter of iterating over this dict to deduplicate it's content.

Comment: I suggest stepping away from the python and describing **in words** how you can solve this problem. Once you clearly understand the steps needed, then you can translate them into python.

Comment: If there are 20 elements in the file with the ID 123456, then there are 20 elements with the same name and the same address. No other entries use that name or that address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all the ids to a set:

```
unique_ids = set(item['id'] for item in my_data.values())
print(len(unique_ids))
```

Comment: You can make this ever so slightly faster by using a set comprehension `{item['id'] for item in my_data.values()}`

Comment: With `my_data.values()` being what exactly? I open the file through `with open(file.json) as file:` and then `data = json.load(file)`

Comment: Well, then use `data` instead of `my_data`.